# R, time-variable as factor. How to find the value closest to a certain time?

Tags: r, date, time

I am working in Rstudio, and I have a factor variable "Time". So, an example of the value that I see could be "10:17:38". Objective: I want to find out which observation in the dataset is closest to a certain time, say "09:58:13". How can I do that in Rstudio?

I have tried to add the value "09:58:13" as a separate variable, for example "Fixed_time" (the same value for all observations). Then the idea was to create a new variable by saying difference=Time-Fixed_time and finding the minimal absolute value of "difference". The problem is that I never managed to get a format that would allow me to subtract one from another. I have tried as.POSIXct which also adds today's year, month and day that I do not need in my variable. Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know R but, it's probably be helpful to see a short bit of code showing how you're loading your non-fixed time values, so it's obvious what data type they're actually stored as. From your question it looks like they might be strings?

Comment: I wonder if you could try converting the time values to the `difftime` class and then run some code that takes the difference. If you had some practice data, I could workshop it a bit and code out what I've talking about.

Comment: The easiest way to do it would be: `dput(head(data))`. Then you just copy the output to an edited version of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, an example dataset is important.

Without knowing your data, I recommend to add the day itself in order to avoid problems at the change of day (midnight).

You can change the following code according to your needs. Please note some lines of code are inserted for test case only - see what happens.

```
# --- Create some data ---
dat <- read.table(textConnection("date time observation
2019-11-01 15:01:32 100
2019-11-01 18:26:31 115
2019-11-01 10:17:38 51
2019-11-01 20:23:21 278"), header=TRUE) 
dat

# --- set certain time ---
CertainTime <- "2019-11-01 09:58:13"
SmallestValue <- 86400 # seconds of one day

for(i in 1:4) {
  ObservationTime <- paste(dat[i,1],dat[i,2])
  diff <- difftime(CertainTime, ObservationTime, units = "secs")
  print("-------------------")
  print(CertainTime)
  print(ObservationTime, max.levels=0)
  print(paste("Index", i, "time diff ", diff, "to certain time.")) 


  if(diff*(-1) < SmallestValue){
    SmallestValue <- diff*(-1) 
    print("smaller value found")
    print(SmallestValue)
    SmallestValueindex <- i
  }  
}

print(SmallestValueindex)
print(SmallestValue)

# print oberservation data
print (paste ("Date:", dat[SmallestValueindex,1], "Time:", dat[SmallestValueindex,2], "Observation:", dat[SmallestValueindex,3]))
```

**Output of last line of code:**

```
[1] "Date: 2019-11-01 Time: 10:17:38 Observation: 51"
```